# Highcharts datalabel 'callout' shape not working for donut chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I've been trying to implement dynamic 'callout' shape datalabels for donut chart using Highcharts javascript library, where notch of datalabels point to respective arc. 
something like this: https://imgur.com/yKhWKOu

I've created the 'callout' shape using highcharts renderer method, but unable to make it dynamic. This is what I'm getting right now: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXtuN.jpg
My code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; max-width: 600px; margin: 0 auto"></div>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(Highcharts) {
    Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.callout = function(x, y, w, h) {
      var arrowLength = 6,
        halfDistance = 6,
        r = Math.min(0, w, h),
        safeDistance = r + halfDistance,
        <!-- anchorX = options && options.anchorX,
        //anchorY = options && options.anchorY, 
        path;
      path = [
        'M', x + r, y,      // 
        'L', x + w - r, y, // top side  
        'C', x + w, y, x + w, y, x + w, y + r, // top-right corner  
        'L', x + w, y + h - r, // right side 
        'C', x + w, y + h, x + w, y + h, x + w - r, y + h, // bottom-right corner 
        'L', x + r, y + h, // bottom side 
        'C', x, y + h, x, y + h, x, y + h - r, // bottom-left corner 
        'L', x, y + r, // left side 
        'C', x, y, x, y, x + r, y // top-right corner
      ];
      path.splice(23, 
        3,
        'L',
        w / 2 + halfDistance,
        y + h,
        w / 2, 
        y + h + arrowLength,
        w / 2 - halfDistance, 
        y + h,
        x + r, 
        y + h
      );
      return path;
    };
  }(Highcharts));

  Highcharts.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          style: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            color: 'white'
          },
          connectorWidth: 0,
          distance: 10, 
          shape: 'callout',
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          <!-- backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)', -->
          style: {
            color: '#FFFFFF',
            textOutline: 'none'
          }
        },
        startAngle: 0,
        endAngle: 360,
        center: ['50%', '50%']
      }
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'pie',
      innerSize: '80%',
      data: [
        ['Firefox', 10.38],
        ['IE', 56.33],
        ['Chrome', 24.03],
        ['Opera', 31.44]
      ]
    }]
  }, function(chart) {

  });
  </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

'Thanks in advance'

Answer (score 0):

I examined this subject and it seems that it's rather tricky thing to do in Highcharts.

The library uses `SVGRenderer.label` (https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label) function for creating the data labels.

Chevron (small arrow) appears in `callout` shape label only when `xAnchor` and `yAnchor` are definded and necessary conditions from the `Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols.callout` function are satisfied (https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/js/parts/SvgRenderer.js). When data labels are generated for pie series these values are not defined - chevron doesn't appear.

You have overwritten this function and hardcoded the label path - that's not the solution when you want it to be responsive.

Here's a **workaround** that I found:

I set `dataLabels.format` to empty string - the label are generated, but they're not visible, because they have no content. I use their position in `chart.events.render` to generate new labels:

```
  render: function() {
    var chart = this,
      series = chart.series[0],
      renderer = chart.renderer;

    series.points.forEach(function(p) {
      var dl = p.dataLabel,
        x = dl.x + chart.plotLeft,
        y = dl.y + chart.plotTop,
        chartCenterX = chart.chartWidth / 2,
        chartCenterY = chart.chartHeight / 2,
        anchorX,
        anchorY;

      // destroy the old label
      if (dl.customLabel) {
        dl.customLabel.destroy();
      }

      // definitions for all the directions
      if (x < chartCenterX && y < chartCenterY) { // right bottom corner chevron
        anchorX = x + 30;
        anchorY = y + 50;
      } // more should be added here

      // create custom label
      dl.customLabel = renderer.label(p.name, x, y, 'callout', anchorX, anchorY).attr({
        fill: 'blue'
      }).css({
        color: 'white'
      }).add();

    });
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/8s968m7f/

The biggest challenge here is to find a proper coordinates for anchors. I only did that for the label(s) in the top-left part of the plot area (it's just for example purposes - better formulas need to be found). I used the dimensions of the chart to compute these values.

It's not very elegant solution, but if you find proper formulas and do some coding it'll work.